# Save sequence of variables into list without having to write them individually

Tags: r

Say I have vectors:

```
p1 <- c(1:10)
p2 <- c(1:20)
p3 <- c(1:30)
```

To save them into a list I would:

```
mylist <- list(p1,p2,p3)
```

Having more variables would make this very typing intensive. Is there a way/function to leverage the fact the variable are in sequence?
e.g.

```
mylist <- list(somefunction(paste0("p",1:3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get()` inside a mapping function such as `lapply()` and `purrr::map()`:

```
n = 3
purrr::map(paste0('p', 1:n), get)
lapply(paste0('p', 1:n), get)
```

Edit: is better to use `mget()` as @Ronak pointed out

Comment: You may use `mget` instead - `mget(paste0("p", 1:n))`